# How to interact with Kafka from IBM APIconnect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apiconnect

I am trying to interact with Apache Kafka from  IBM APIConnect toolkit.
I have installed Kafka Connector provided in DataSource tab of API Connect and created a         Blank Model referring to the Kafka DataBase and placed the below     code in /common/model/Kafka-Model.js.Also I have the Apache Kafka running in my   local.

```
    'use strict';
     var kafka = require('kafka-node');
     var connector = require('loopback-connector-kafka');
     module.exports = function(KafkaModel) {
    function KafkaCreate(){
//var assert = require('assert');
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181');
var topic = 'topicTest12';
var consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(client, [ { topic: topic } ], {});
var producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(client);
var connector = require('loopback-connector-kafka');
var settings = {
connectionString: 'localhost:2181'
}
var dataSource = { settings: settings };
var payloads= [
{ topic: 'topicTest12', messages: 'This is the First Message I am sending', partition: 0 },
];
connector.initialize(dataSource);
consumer.on('message', function (messages) {
//assert.equal(messages.value, 'Hallo');
console.log(messages);
process.exit();
});
consumer.on('error', function (error) {
console.log('Consumer error: ', error);
});
producer.createTopics([ topic ], function (err) {
if (err) {
console.log('Got error when create topic:', err);
return;
}
else {
producer.on('ready', function(){
producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){
console.log(data)
});
});
}
setTimeout(function loop() {
dataSource.connector.send(topic, payloads, function (err) {
if (err) console.log('Got error when send message:', err);
else console.log('Message send');
});
}, 1000);
})
};
KafkaModel.remoteMethod('KafkaCreate',{
returns: { arg:'status',type: 'messages' },
http: { verb: 'post', 'path': '/replaceOrCreate' }
})
};
```

When I am executing the above peice of code in postman with             http://localhost:4001/api/KafkaModels/replaceOrCreate URL with POST method, I am  getting the below error

> `"message": "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined",
>   "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined\n at     SharedMethod.invoke.`

I am not sure whether this is correct approach to interact with Kafka from IBM API Connect or not.Pls suggest if we can do it by any other means.!!.

Comment: Can you please post the code what you have tried?? So that others can get clear idea..

Comment: Your stack trace looks incomplete. Please provide the complete stack trace as well.

Comment: Please find the complete code above.

Comment: @Divya are you still experiencing this issue? If so, can you please provide your full stack trace.